Use of environment variables in Java with Spring Boot
I'm trying to use external environment variables in my Java App based on Spring Boot.
I have declared a class to read the variables from the application. Properties file:
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "etao")
public class ConfigurationData {
    
    private String cronPrintDateTime = "";

    private String searchEngineId = "";
    private String googleApiKey = "";

    public String getCronPrintDateTime() {
        return this.cronPrintDateTime;
    }

    public void setCronPrintDateTime(String cronPrintDateTime) {
        this.cronPrintDateTime = cronPrintDateTime;
    }

    public String getSearchEngineId() {
        return this.searchEngineId;
    }

    public void setSearchEngineId (String searchEngineId) {
        this.searchEngineId = searchEngineId;
    }

    public String getGoogleApiKey () {
        return this.googleApiKey;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiKey (String gooogleApiKey) {
        this.googleApiKey = gooogleApiKey;
    }
}


This works so far as I can use this in another part of the app to read out the environment variable:
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationData configurationData;

    @Scheduled(cron ="0 * * * * ?")
    public void printDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(configurationData.getCronPrintDateTime());
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        Date now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdf.format(now);
        System.out.println("Task executed at: " + strDate);
    }
    
}

Now I try to access the other variables in a different part of the code:
public class GoogleSearch {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationData configurationData;
    
    private String CX_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID;
    private String GOOGLE_API_KEY;

    private Search searchResult;
    // List<Result> searchResultItems;

    public GoogleSearch() {
        this.CX_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = configurationData.getSearchEngineId();
        this.GOOGLE_API_KEY = configurationData.getGoogleApiKey();
    }
   
    // Other code ...

}

Here it fails with:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.demo.views.search.SearchView': Failed to instantiate [com.demo.views.search.SearchView]: Constructor threw exception

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.demo.views.search.SearchView]: Constructor threw exception

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.demo.utils.ConfigurationData.getSearchEngineId()" because "this.configurationData" is null

So yes my constructor failed because configurationData is null so the auto wiring didn't work but I have no clue why?
Do I need to wrap the ConfigurationData.class somehow to be able to generate several instances/Beans of it?

How do you initialize GoogleSearch ?

Try to add @Component to GoogleSearch class so Spring can inject ConfigurationData singleton and change the constructor initialization with a method with @PostConstruct annotation. Why use @PostConstruct?

The autowiring will only take place after the object has been constructed. Use constructor injection if you need to access the object in the constructor.

What does this have to do with environment variables at all? What data do you want to read in? So far your question is "why did my autowiring not work?" but the heading so totally different.

@Valijon, I tried the @Component and @PostConstruct which avoids the error that I am getting but then the variables get never set, so it doesn't work

@M.Deinum, I tried to move the variable initialization out of the Constructor and only later in a function when the variables are used but still no go. The Autowire just doesn't seem to work.

Then you aren't using a Spring Managed instance but are creating an instance of the class yourself.

@cyberbrain please see the second line in ConfigurationData code: @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "etao"). As I said in the text I am reading the environment variables from application.properties file.

environment variables and property files are not the same. In a Windows environment you can list your environment variables with the SET command in Command Prompt or gci env:* in PowerShell. In Linux you would use env in a shell. Spring Boot allows to override properties (from a file) with commandline parameters or from the environment. But all in all you probably just used the wrong terms.

So unrelated to your original question, but interesting for using such external config is the official docs on the Externalized Configuration. Maybe you could rephrase your question a bit so it will not confuse future readers with a similar problem (or a complete different problem they believe to get solved here ;-)

@cyberbrain I can't follow your comments. They are the same external configuration parameters. In the article you referenced about external configuration in Spring it says: 3. Config data such as application.properties and 5. OS environment variables. I don't see how my question is confusing the issue. The point is not how you read them, but how you use them in multiple locations in the code, that's what's not working for here.

If anybody is interested I found a solution that works. Basically I was unable to Autowire the ConfigurationData class in more than one place so I build a service class and autowire ConfigurationData into the service class:
@Service
public class ConfigurationDataService {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationData configurationData;

    public String getCronPrintDateTime() {
        return configurationData.getCronPrintDateTime();
    }

    public String getSearchEngineId() {
        return configurationData.getSearchEngineId();
    }


    public String getGoogleApiKey () {
        return configurationData.getGoogleApiKey();
    }

}

After that instead of using the ConfigurationData directly in ScheduledTasks and in GoogleSearch I inject the ConfigurationDataService class and use this to get the env variables that I need.

What your original code was missing: the class GoogleSearch is not annotated as @Component, it also has to be injected itself (if it is used in another class) to make the injection into that GoogleSearch class happen.
Another alternative would be that you can have the configuration values directly set individually. Here is an example:
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GoogleSearch {
  private final String cxSearchEngineId;

  @Autowired
  public GoogleSearch(@Value("${etao.search-engine-id}") String sei) {
    this.cxSearchEngineId = sei;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void test() {
    System.out.println(cxSearchEngineId);
  }

  // Other code ...
}

I highly recommend to use constructor injection instead of field injection!
Please note that I used the @PostConstruct annotation here just to show that the solution works without big effort. If you add a standard Spring Boot application class, this should be sufficient to see the @Value in action.
